# Fail to Perform build web site in visual studio 2008 -- unrecognized attribute 'targetframework'

Tags: vb.net, razor

I am hopping that someone would be able to help with this issue:

I have an existing asp.net website (Developed in  visual studio 2008) that I have modified, and I am trying to build web site so the namespace library gets updated.

The Issue: Every time, I try to build web site, it comes with the below error:

---

unrecognized attribute maxrequestlength note that attribute names are case sensitive

---

I have checked my website on IIS Application Pool (.Net Framework Ver : 4.0).

The Build Target Framework on Start Option on visual studio 2008  :2.0

I hope I could some help as I am go crazy.

Cheers
AM:)_

Comment: can you post full error with details

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, It appears that the .NET is not set to 4.0 everywhere. You may have it set at 2.0 somewhere

Perhaps the answer is the following

Your app still configured as net framework 2.0 application. You need to configure application pool to use net framework 4,
Ask your hosting provider to setup .net 4 for you

https://forums.asp.net/t/1928981.aspx?Parser+Error+Message+Unrecognized+attribute+targetFramework+Note+that+attribute+names+are+case+sensitive+